# Symfony backend: specific test on field before insert

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4

am using the symfony's admin generator,
in the "new" interface, i have one specific field that i want to test before insert into database, and if it doesn't pass i return the user to the same interface until he gets the right value !
can any body tell me how it can be done?

for the one who voted down on my question : am not looking for a simple validator, what i want is that a url field i check whether it IP existe in my DB and then add it (avoid adding all external urls)

Comment: for the one who voted down on my question :
am not looking for a simple validator, what i want is that a url field i check whether it IP existe in my DB and then add it (avoid adding all external urls)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading your question an your comment on the negative vote, is clear that you need a custom validator class. You need to create a custom validator [[link](http://www.symfony-project.org/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/10-Forms#chapter_10_custom_widget_and_validator_classes)] and make it do what you want it to do.

What I understood from your question, is that you want to get the IP address from a URL and check if the IP address exists in the DB, Symfony doesn't have a built in validator for something like this. That is why you need to create the validator yourself.

Comment: thanks Ramy, am not looking for a soluton for the ip check, all what i needed was how to create a costum validator !
Thanks Man !